# Show Image based off Textbox Property

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a Textbox object in SSRS that returns 1 record from a dataset of "Critical", "Warning" or "Normal".

Depending on which text is returned, I want to show the appropriate embedded image which are also named "Critical", "Warning", "Normal".

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an images folder on your report server and place your images there.  The example below would point to a folder sharing the same parent as the folder your report is in.
Then add the following to the expression in the images property, on the general tab.  Under "Use this image".

You'll also want to make sure the image source is set to external on the same tab.

```
=Switch(Fields!Textbox1.Value = "Critcal", "../images/Critical.jpg",
  Fields!Textbox1.Value = "Warning", "../images/Warning.jpg",
  Fields!Textbox1.Value = "Normal", "../images/Normal.jpg")
```

Comment: Thanks 4Logik, is it possible to refer to the embedded images within the report itself though rather than storing the images on the server itself?

Comment: I tried this and it shows the Normal image no matter whether its Critical, Warning or Normal =IIF(Fields!MonitorStatus.Value = "Critical", "Critical", IIF(Fields!MonitorStatus.Value = "Warning", "Warning", "Normal"))

Answer (score 0):

I finished up doing this which worked perfectly:

=IIF(Fields!OverallStatus.Value = "Critical", "Critical", IIF(Fields!OverallStatus.Value = "Warning", "Warning", "Normal"))